# Tikz connection problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)},node distance=1.5cm]
% We start by placing the blocks
    \node [input, name=input,label=below:$\xi_{k}$] {};
    \node [sum, left of=input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, left of=sum, node distance=3cm] (Ck) {$C_k$};
    \node [left of=sum, node distance=2cm,label=below:$y_{k+1}$] (div) {};
    \node [block,above right=0.5cm and 0.1cm of div] (zm1) {$z^{-1}$};
    \node [block,above right=0.5cm and 1cm of div] (Ak) {$A_k$};
    \node [output,left of=Ck,label=below:$w_k$,node distance=0.6cm] (output) {};

    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- (sum);
    \draw [draw,->] (sum) -- (Ck);
    \draw [->] (zm1) -- (Ak);
    \draw [draw,->] (Ak) -| node[pos=0.97,right] {+} (sum);
    \fill (div) circle [radius=1.5pt];
    \draw [->] (div) |- (zm1);
    \draw [draw,->] (Ck) -- (output);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which outputs:

[image]

For some reason the arrow going from the black circle connection does not touch the circle (see above in red). How do I fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nodes have padding, try `inner sep=0pt` on that one. Or draw to `div.center`

Comment: kill `outer sep` also: `outer sep=0pt`-

Comment: @daleif Want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. done

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to rewrite your code as follows:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 9mm,
       sum/.style = {circle,draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=1ex,
                     node contents={}},
     block/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, minimum size=3ex}
                        ]
    \coordinate[label=below:$\xi_{k}$]                  (input);
        \node (sum) [sum,left=of input];
    \coordinate[left=22mm of sum,label=below:$y_{k+1}$] (div);
        \node (Ck)  [block,left=of div]  {$C_k$};
    \coordinate[left=of Ck,label=below:$w_k$]           (output);
    %
        \node (zm1) [block,above right=5mm and 3mm of div]  {$z^{-1}$};
        \node (Ak)  [block,right=3mm of zm1]                {$A_k$};
    %
    \path[draw,->]  (input) edge (sum)      (sum) edge (Ck)  
                    (Ck)    edge (output)   (zm1)    --  (Ak);
    \draw[->]       (div) |- (zm1);      
    \draw[->]       (Ak) -| (sum) node[above right] {+};
    \fill[black]    (div) circle (1.5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

In it for `input`, `div` and `output`  I use `\coordinate` instead of nodes. With this I eliminate all `sep` defined for nodes. As can be seen, I also reorganize your code. In this for positioning I use correct notation, for example `left=of div` (instead obsolete `left of=div`).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `div` node has no data, but nodes have paddig, so either

1. add `inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt`, to the definition of `div`, or
2. draw to `div.center` instead of just `div`